# jQuery animated search box with ul/li

Tags: jquery, css

Would you please teach me how to mimic the navigation bar like http://societeperrier.com/ ?
I've tried so many ways but in vain. I'm using  http://thefinishedbox.com/freebies/scripts/jquery-animated-search/ as my search box.
While when I put it with my ul/li navigation bar. It pre-leaves a blank for the post-slided effect.
As you see in Societe Perrier. The li items will auto rearrange after the search box being clicked.

Sorry for my poor English and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it, here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GsGHs/).

```
$("#search").focus(function(){

    // animate right 100px, you can change the values after
    $(this).animate({'width' : "200px" }, 200);

});

$("#search").blur(function(){

   // change back after blur is fired
   $(this).animate({'width' : "100px" }, 200);

});
```

​

Comment: thank you for your fast replying! 
Still have some problems.
I'm using wordpress with wp_enquene_script('jquery');
how could I insert these codes without any java crashes?

Answer (score 1):

I've used same jQuery plugin and faced similar problem.  To solve this problem, I removed width of fieldset from css and applied width on 'focus' event in js file.  Added code is given below:

```
$('#searchForm fieldset').animate({width: '240px'}, 300);
```

On 'blur' event we need to re size that parent element as well.  So I added below line in blur event:

```
$('#searchForm fieldset').animate({width: '152px'}, 300);
```

You can set width of your choice.  I'm not sure whether it is perfect or not but it worked for me.